# Migration from D7 to D8 is failing with a source plugin exception

Tags: drupal-8

I've installed the migration-plus module and used it successfully for other migrations on this project. When I try to use it with Simplenews it fails with this error:

```
[error]  Migration failed with source plugin exception: tid is defined as a source ID but has no value.
```

I installed and configured Simplenews on D8. I imported the migration yml files from the Simplenews module and ran it with 'drush migrate-import d7_simplenews_newsletter'. I've tried it with and without a custom key for the d7 database. I've tried it with and without recreating the D7 newsletter categories in D8.

I expected to see it successfully migrate the Simplenews newsletters from D7 to D8 but it's not working. I'm not defining 'tid' as a source ID in the migration, so where is it coming from and what is causing it to fail?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem was, but upgrading to the latest dev version of D8 Simplenews fixed it.